# В цикле проверить совпадение счетчика с массивом

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно в цикле, указать выходные дни по конкретным месяцам, например месяц 11, если `i === 3`, то `weekendsDisabled = true`, и так далее по JSON массиву. В общем, в массиве `currentMonthDays` у значения `weekendsDisabled` будет true || false в зависимости от дней из массива `weekendsDays`   Я что-то туплю, как это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста

```js
weekendsJson: [
  {
    "month": 1,
    "days": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30"
  },
  {
    "month": 2,
    "days": "5,6,12,13,19,20,22*,23,26,27"
  },
  {
    "month": 3,
    "days": "5*,6,7+,8,12,13,19,20,26,27"
  },
  {
    "month": 4,
    "days": "2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30"
  },
  {
    "month": 5,
    "days": "1,2+,3+,7,8,9,10+,14,15,21,22,28,29"
  },
  {
    "month": 6,
    "days": "4,5,11,12,13+,18,19,25,26"
  },
  {
    "month": 7,
    "days": "2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30,31"
  },
  {
    "month": 8,
    "days": "6,7,13,14,20,21,27,28"
  },
  {
    "month": 9,
    "days": "3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25"
  },
  {
    "month": 10,
    "days": "1,2,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30"
  },
  {
    "month": 11,
    "days": "3*,4,5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27"
  },
  {
    "month": 12,
    "days": "3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25,31"
  }
];

const currentMonthDays = [];
const currentMonth = 11
const currentYear = 2022
const weekendsDays = weekendsJson[currentMonth - 1].days.split(',')

for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  currentMonthDays.push({ day: i, month: currentMonth, year: currentYear, weekendsDisabled: '?' });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, воспользоваться методом **includes** и проверять список выходных дней с текущим элементом

```js
const weekendsJson = [
  {
    "month": 1,
    "days": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30"
  },
  {
    "month": 2,
    "days": "5,6,12,13,19,20,22*,23,26,27"
  },
  {
    "month": 3,
    "days": "5*,6,7+,8,12,13,19,20,26,27"
  },
  {
    "month": 4,
    "days": "2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30"
  },
  {
    "month": 5,
    "days": "1,2+,3+,7,8,9,10+,14,15,21,22,28,29"
  },
  {
    "month": 6,
    "days": "4,5,11,12,13+,18,19,25,26"
  },
  {
    "month": 7,
    "days": "2,3,9,10,16,17,23,24,30,31"
  },
  {
    "month": 8,
    "days": "6,7,13,14,20,21,27,28"
  },
  {
    "month": 9,
    "days": "3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25"
  },
  {
    "month": 10,
    "days": "1,2,8,9,15,16,22,23,29,30"
  },
  {
    "month": 11,
    "days": "3,4,5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27"
  },
  {
    "month": 12,
    "days": "3,4,10,11,17,18,24,25,31"
  }
];

const currentMonthDays = [];
const currentMonth = 11
const currentYear = 2022
const weekendsDays = weekendsJson[currentMonth - 1].days.split(',');

for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  currentMonthDays.push({ day: i, month: currentMonth, year: currentYear, weekendsDisabled: weekendsDays.includes(i.toString()) });
}

console.log(currentMonthDays);
```

И обратите внимание, что не в каждом месяце 30 дней.

Comment: Да месяц у меня динамический вычисляется, это я для удобства примера показал, спасибо, как же я не догадался до includes(